# How do I change the colour of a cell based on the values listed in a table on another page?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The table of where I'd like coloured in is seen in the image I attached.

I am working on a rather large equipment tracker for my company. I have a named table that lists the various brands of equipment and the different titles for them.

On another page I have these as drop down options in a list I will be having contractors use to sign out equipment from our building. When they select "Ford" I have all of the Ford Plates drop down in the "Equipment Title" column. There is a separate column also listed "In/Out".

My goal is to have the "equipment titles" highlighted on the "Data sheet" if they are currently signed out. If they have been signed back in then I wouldn't need anything done.

Since there are two conditions, the equipment title appearing in a column, and the in/out being out most recently, I'm not sure how to use the "IF(AND())" formula. Heck, I'm not even sure if that would work for this issue.

I understand that I could change the tracker itself to something where I list all the equipment, or have the contractors sign it out and back in on the same row, but my concern is that if it is too complicated then it will end up not being used.

Any suggestions or thoughts are appreciated.

I've tried the IF(AND()) function in several different capacities under the conditional formatting. I am unsure how to make it register the entire columns, 'Large Equipment Tracker'!$B$2:$B$600 , and  Large Equipment Tracker'!$D$2:$D$600 .

Comment: My recent attempt was 

=IF(AND'Large Equipment Tracker'!$D$2:$D$600=Data!$L$17:$Y$33,'Large Equipment Tracker'!$B$2:$B$600=$H$3)TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a picture of what you want.  Not quite getting my mind around it.   Your Large Equipment Tracker is an actual Excel table and not just a range of formatted cells? i.e. when you select a cell in the table an extra "Table Design" tab appears on the ribbon tabs.  You then have another sheet (the "Data" sheet?) with drop-downs?

Comment: If you use `AND` you don't need to use `IF` as well.  The AND function will return TRUE/FALSE.  Wrapping it in an `IF` formula will just read as `IF TRUE = TRUE THEN TRUE`.  Looking at your example formula you're asking is the range D2:D600 the same as the range L17:Y33.  They'll never be the same - the two ranges are different sizes.

Comment: On a smaller scale this works:  `=AND(A1:B2=D1:E2,ISNUMBER(MATCH($H$2,'Large Equipment Tracker'!$B$2:$B$600)))`  this checks that the cells in A1:B2 match those in D1:E2 (i.e. A1=D1, B1=E1, A2=D2, B2=E2) and that the value in H2 appears somewhere in the range B2:B600.  Match will return a number or an #N/A, so ISNUMBER checks that and returns TRUE/FALSE.